# UnboundID trying to add attribute getting an exception

Tags: java, unboundid-ldap-sdk, unboundid

Using an LDAP connecting I am trying to write a method that adds/replaces an attribute "postalCode" for a user in the database.

```
public void addPostcodeAttributeToUser(String postcode, String user, LDAPConnection conn) {
    try {
        Modification mod = new Modification(REPLACE, "postalCode", postcode);
        LDAPModification ldapMod = new LDAPModification(mod);
        conn.modify("cn=" + user + ",ou=Users,dc=home", ldapMod);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Issue modifying ldap");
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting the exception "Issue modifying ldap"? I have tried both ModificationType.REPLACE and ModificationType.ADD both giving the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Looked through the logs and my ldap connection was failing to connect due to a typo in the config. This method works as intended.